# I want to add parameters in div element with React

Tags: reactjs

I want to add parameters in div element with React.

This code not working:

```
function Slider() {

  const bg1 =' data-background="images/slider/slider1.jpg"';

  return (<>

    <div className="slider-area over-hidden" {bg1}></div>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create an object with the parameter.

```
const bg1 = {
    "data-background": "image/slider/slider1.jpg"
}

<div className="slider-area over-hidden" {...bg1}></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of your attributes you want to add to the div.

```
function Slider() {
  const attrs = { 'data-background': 'images/slider/slider1.jpg' };

  return (<div className="slider-area over-hidden" {...attrs} />);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Slider() {

  const bg1 =' data-background="images/slider/slider1.jpg"';

  return (<>

    <div className="slider-area over-hidden" `${bg1}`></div>
                                             ^ add this operator
    );
}
```

Comment: Huh. I had not known about this use case, or this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for 3 reasons:

1. There is no closing `</>` for your opening `<>` so that will bomb your program.
2. This `className="slider-area over-hidden" {bg1}` is not how you concat a string in JSX. Rather, this is how it needs to be done `className={"slider-area over-hidden" + bg1}`
3. And finally, `data-background="images/slider/slider1.jpg"` is not how you would add a an attribute to an element. Instead, as pointed out by the others, this is how to do it:

```
  const attrs = {'data-background': 'images/slider/slider1.jpg'};

  return (<div className="slider-area over-hidden" {...attrs} ></div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const tabs = {"dadosFuncionais" : {'data-te-nav-active':''}, "dadosPessoais": {}}
    
    const [tabSelected, setTabSelected] = useState(tabs)
    
    const handleTabsClick = async (event) => {
        console.log(tabSelected)
        switch(event.target.dataset.menu) {
          case 'dadosFuncionais':
            console.log('dados funcionais '+tabSelected.dadosFuncionais)
            setTabSelected({"dadosFuncionais" : {'data-te-nav-active':''}, "dadosPessoais": {}})
            break;
          case 'dadosPessoais':
            console.log('dados pessoais '+tabSelected.dadosPessoais)
            setTabSelected({"dadosFuncionais" : {}, "dadosPessoais": {'data-te-nav-active':''}})
            break;
          default:
            // code block
        }
      }

HTML:

    <li role="presentation">
    <a
      href="#tabs-home"
      className="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
      data-te-toggle="pill"
      data-te-target="#tabs-home"
      {...(tabSelected.dadosFuncionais)}
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tabs-home"
      aria-selected='false'
      data-menu="dadosFuncionais"
      onClick={handleTabsClick}
      >Dados Funcionais</a
    >
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a
      href="#tabs-profile"
      className="my-2 block border-x-0 border-b-2 border-t-0 border-transparent px-7 pb-3.5 pt-4 text-xs font-medium uppercase leading-tight text-neutral-500 hover:isolate hover:border-transparent hover:bg-neutral-100 focus:isolate focus:border-transparent data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary dark:text-neutral-400 dark:hover:bg-transparent dark:data-[te-nav-active]:border-primary-400 dark:data-[te-nav-active]:text-primary-400"
      data-te-toggle="pill"
      data-te-target="#tabs-profile"
      {...(tabSelected.dadosPessoais)}
      role="tab"
      aria-controls="tabs-profile"
      aria-selected='false'
      data-menu="dadosPessoais"
      onClick={handleTabsClick}
      >Dados Pessoais</a
    >
  </li>
```